# Resolution drops upon wake from suspend - 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, resolution, suspend

Whenever I wake my computer from suspend, the resolution is significantly lower than where I have it set. However, if I simply open System Settings, the resolution instantly resets itself to where it should be (1280x1024).

Any idea why this might be happening?

I'm running 14.04 LTS. I have an NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT, and I'm using the latest recommented NVIDIA Binary driver, 331.38 (proprietary, tested).

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify that following questions:

1. Did you have installed the NVIDIA card after installing Ubuntu, e.g This card was not present when you were installing Ubuntu?
2. Did you have removed or disabled and then re-installed the card after installing Ubuntu?

Comment: The card *was* present when I installed Ubuntu, and I have not removed or disabled it. By default the nouveau driver was being used, so the only change I made was from the nouveau driver to the proprietary NVIDIA driver. This solved other instability issues I was having.